# Is there any way to print error message in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restful

I am using python code to print an error message but it doesn't return.

Data file google sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vq8lGNjVIN_oVSN5fS8dIH5In4-vcpSB5IxxDAP5SzI/edit?usp=sharing

[Error message code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iKqH.png)

If recommendation belongs to the target variable will be print else give an error but not actually happened.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort
import json
import sys
import random
import unicodedata
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

data = pd.read_csv("clean_o2h.csv", sep=",")


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])



def predict_word():
    print(request.get_json())
    sent = request.get_json()['smiles']
    reactants = data["reactants"].tolist()
    targets = data["targets"].tolist()
    error = ("plese enter correct smiles") 

# TFIDF vector representation
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(targets)

    test = vectorizer.transform([sent])

#test = vectorizer.transform(["NC1=CC=C2C(COC(N[C@H]3C4=C(CC3)C=CC=C4)=N2)=C1"])

    cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(test, X).flatten()
    l = []
   # n = ["Result 1","Result 2", "Result 3","Result 4"]

# Extract top 5 similarity records
    similarity = cosine_similarities.argsort()[:-5:-1]
     #print("Top 5 recommendations...")
    for sim in similarity:
    #print(reactants[sim])
       result = reactants[sim]
       l.append(result)
       print(l)

      # output = dict(zip(l,n))
       res = { i : l[i] for i in range(0, len(l) ) }



    #return  jsonify({"Recommendation": res})

    if(sent == targets):
      return jsonify({"Recommendation": res})
    else:
           return jsonify({"Error": error})




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='8080')
```

you can see in the image I put random value but error message not printed.

Comment: I think a better way is to `throw` an error and then `catch` it where you want to show it

Comment: @bhaskar can you help me with the code?

Comment: try:
         sent == targets
         return jsonify({"Recommendation": res})
    
    except :
      print("exception")
      return jsonify({"Error": error})
I try with this code but not working

Comment: You could also try using a logger instead of `print` messages. This would then show up on your server. e.g. the inbuilt python logging library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), or better still logzero (https://logzero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks! it is working